# Maven Release issue with forked deploy process with proxy authorization as argument fails with 407 proxy authorization require

Tags: java, mule, maven-3, maven-release-plugin, http-status-code-407

I'm looking for your help and advise in one maven Release Build issue which is intermittent.

I'm trying to use Maven Release having Mule Maven deploy plugin to deploy using proxy which requires proxy authrorisation so my maven command is as below-

mvn release:prepare release:perform -X -Darguments="-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttps.proxyUser=user -Dhttps.proxyPassword=password -Dhttps.proxyPort=80"

Throwing error-
maven release perform -mule maven deploy 407 proxy authorization require.

Analysis-
When i check the proxy server logs,I see it is successful when the proxyUser gets passed to the proxy server but fails when it is not.My command is not changed an no changes in proxy server. Moreover maven settings.xml also has proxy credentials configured.
Please advise how I can make sure that proxy user/password details are passed correctly? I think the issue is Maven Release forking new process of Mule Deploy which is not able to pass the parameters to Mule deploy.

Snapshot Build/Deploy works fine and the same maven deploy is invoked using proxy details and it's fine.In the POM deploy goal is same.
However the arguments has to be passed in below way unlike maven release way of passing parameter.
mvn clean deploy -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttps.proxyUser=user -Dproxyhttps.proxyPassword=password -Dphttps.proxyPort=80.

The issue is only with Maven Release and not taking the authorization parameter and behaving intermittently.

Please help.

Thanks,
Siddharth

Comment: This seems to be a pure Maven issue. I'm not sure why it is tagged as [mule].

Comment: Mule is tagged so that if any user has faced the same problem they can advise. Do you know any solution?I have tried the commenting below-but still not working#jdk.http.auth.proxying.disabledSchemes=
 #jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=Basic